# How to make a capital delta in asciimath notation

Tags: tinymce, ascii, mathjax, asciimath

I am using asciimath, mathjax, and tinymce, and for some reason the lowercase delta and capital delta are the same thing.

The lowercase looks like a cursive-y d, and uppercase is supposed to be a triangle right?

I can't figure out if this is a bug of if I'm missing something.

There's a demo of what I'm trying to do [here](http://www.imathas.com/editordemo/demo.html), click on the summation symbol in the menu to see what I'm talking about. It has the same issue.

Suggestions?

Edit:
Actually, I just looked at it again, and all of the greek letters where both lowercase and capital are listed are having this problem.

Comment: Using ```Delta``` etc. works here.

Comment: What browser does exhibit this problem?

Comment: also in IE9, "`Delta`" has the same output (and the same icon in the pop-up) as "`delta`".